# Linear operator of infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $T: V\rightarrow V$ a linear operator with finite dimension.
>
> - If exists a linear operator $U: V\rightarrow V$ such that $TU=I$, prove that $T$ is invertible.
> - Prove that if the dimension of $V$ is infinite, the previous result is false (give an example)

Comment: What examples of infinite dimensional spaces are you familiar with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In finite dimensional spaces $V$, a linear operator $T:V\to V$ is invertible iff it is onto. The condition $TU=I$ implies that $T$ is onto.

In infinite dimensions, let $V=\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\}$, and 
$$
\big(T(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\big)_k=a_{k+1}
$$ 
and 
$$
\big(U(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\big)_k=a_{k-1}
$$
Then $TU=I$, but $T$ is not invertible! It is not onto.

Comment: What is $a_0$ in defining $(U(a_n))_1$? (This is essentially correct, of course, but this is a valid concern.)

Comment: A simple explicit example is $T\colon V\to V$ defined by “multiply by $x$” where $V$ is the space of polynomials with real coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is finite-dimensional then $T$ is a matrix. If $TU=I$ then the determinant of $T$ is nonzero, so that it is invertible.

You cannot make this argument in the infinite dimensional case.